# Error installing Postgres on Mac

Tags: mac, postgresql

I'm trying to install Postgres on my Mac using brew but for some reason it's unable to finish the installation and is displaying the error below.

"initdb: file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/postgres.bki" does not exist
This might mean you have a corrupted installation or identified
the wrong directory with the invocation option -L.
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully"

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291594/unable-to-install-postgresql-on-my-mac-os-x-machine-via-homebrew

do  `chown -R user/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`

then `brew link postgres`

and `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8`

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work :/

Comment: What happened when you ran brew link postgres also have you installed postgres with brew before?

Comment: gave the same error

Comment: run brew doctor and post what it says